# Android webview performance issues. prevent recreation by storing in top level view

Tags: android, performance, webview

I have some performance issues with the webview.
My application uses fragments. When a user navigates to a certain fragment it inserts a webview (containing facebook comments) 
Navigation between the fragment happens quite a lot. The result is that on every fragment change the webview needs to be re-initiated. This takes easily up to 2-5 seconds. This gives a bad user experience.

I am wondering if it is possible to inject a webview in a top level view which is not part of the fragment. Of course the webview needs to be hidden. 
Then when i construct a fragment i want to extract the webview from the view and insert it into the fragment. when user navigates away i place the webview back in the top level view.
Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Do all of your fragments belong to the same `Activity`?

Comment: yes. they all belong to the same activity.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to keep the state of the fragment. Refer to [`Fragment.onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [`WebView.saveState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState(android.os.Bundle))